# Which wiki satisfies ACL ADI and API?

Tags: wiki

I'm looking for a Wiki System that satisfies the following requirements:

1. Uses ACL (Access Control lists - who can access what pages)
2. Needs to be able to integrate with  Active Directory
3. Is scriptable via an API 
   (meaning I can create a wiki page through an API in
   a program instead of logging in and manually typing in the page.)

The scope of this project is to integrate an in-house version of github - that auto generates, and populates a wiki entry for each project repository, when it is created. Since it is in-house - the need for ACL's and Active directory integration.

Any help in pointing me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please use complete sentences and correct spelling when asking your question.

Comment: @goutham - you may be interested in http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wikispeedia

Comment: All the answers below satisfy conditions 1 and 2 but no one talks about answering or how item 3 in his question is specifically answered. I am not sure why people are upvoting the below answers?

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint can include a wiki. That would cover all of your named requirements. It might not cover any un-named requirements.

Comment: This is a bad, really bad wiki. Actually it is not a wiki.

Comment: @Mircea Vutcovici, SP2010 includes a Wiki function that isn't terribly dissimilar to other wikis and fulfills his other requirements. It might not be most people's first choice, but it works.

Comment: Mircea - like I said, if he has any specific requirements in regards to how wiki-like it needs to be, he didn't bother telling us. I answered the question he asked.

Comment: i will look into  sharepoint wiki

Comment: I tried to use the wiki from SP2007 and it was like using Word 95 to create HTML files. I still have nightmares. It was included just to make another check mark on the list of "features".

Comment: Share point or media wiki which one i have to use still in confusion

Comment: Be aware that sharepoint only works fully with Internet Explorer. Some features are not available on other browsers like Firefox or Google Chrome, you may want to test them. For instance when we tested it, we had to edit the html contents of wiki pages under firefox, as the WYSIWYG was only available for IE and there was no wiki markup.

Answer (score 2):

Mediawiki won't do all that "out of the box" but there are add-ons to cover the bits it won't do natively. It has the added bonus of being the most flexible and most supported wiki around.

Comment: The scope of this project is to integrate an in-house version of github - that auto generates, and populates a wiki entry for each project repository, when it is created.   Since it is in-house - the need for ACL's and Active directory integration.

Answer (score 1):

Mindtouch should also fit your requirements.  http://www.mindtouch.com/

Comment: Can you clarify?  There are three versions - the free/core and then the hosted versions per user.

Answer (score 0):

http://fosiki.org - fully strong and long lived project for enterprise data-wiki. :)